# Formateo Dinámico de un JTextField

Tags: java

Buenos días,
Tengo el siguiente Problema.
Tengo una TextField y un ComboBox el cual se despliega y puede seleccionar una cantidad de Decimales para que eso se refleje en el TextField en tiempo de ejecución.

Para que se entienda mejor, pego una imagen de lo que necesito:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si selecciono el 2 por ejemplo, en el TextField que van números Float, no puedo escribir un numero que contenga mas de 2 cifras despues del punto, es decir, no puedo escribir numero como : 12.456, sino que solo permita ingresar números con un un máximo de lo que seleccione en el combo. Si es dos, números como 34.56 si elijo 3: 45.789 y así con cada selección.
Es posible hacer esto?

Hice este método, pero no me está funcionando:

```
public void FormatearTextFieldFloat(JComboBox cb, JTextField j1) {

    String decimal = cb.getSelectedItem().toString();

    String formato;

    switch(decimal) {
    case "1"  :  formato="#";
    break;
    case "2"  :  formato="##";
    break;
    case "3"  :  formato="###";
    break;
    case "4"  :  formato="####";
    break;
    case "5"  :  formato="#####";
    break;
    default   :  formato="-";
    break;
    }

    DecimalFormat formatoDecimal = new DecimalFormat("##########."+formato);

    j1.setText(formatoDecimal.format(j1.getText()));

}
```

Muchas Gracias por su aporte. Estoy iniciando en esto y se me complica poder hacer ciertas cosas.
Agradezco todo aporte que me ayude con este tema.

Este tema es diferente a: ¿Como limitar la cantidad de decimales de un double?
No estoy solicitando el formato de un numero solamente, sino que lo haga de manera dinamica tomando los decimales de un JComboBox y luego agregue el Valor formateado en una tabla.

Realice el siguiente método pero me da un error:

```
public static String FormatearTextFieldFloat(JComboBox cb, JTextField j1) {

    String decimal = cb.getSelectedItem().toString();

    return String.format("%."+decimal+"f", Float.parseFloat(j1.getText()));

}
```

En la Línea: String decimal = cb.getSelectedItem().toString(); Se supone que traigo el valor que esta seleccionado dentro del Combo, pero se produce un error. Si lo reemplazo por : "2" o cualquier otro valor que figure en el combo, funciona correctamente.
Es posible que por mas que seleccione desde el ComBox y luego se llame a este metodo, no tenga valor alguno?

Comment: ¿El problema entonces es manejar el evento?

Comment: El Problema es que cuando selecciono una opcion del combo, sea ese el valor maximo de decimales que puede tener el JTextField.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado, le paso al momento del evento, los dos JComboBox y eso hace que actualice los dos combos en tiempo de ejecución con la cantidad de decimales que elija del mismo.
Les paso el codigo por si le sirve a alguien.

```
public static String FormatearTextFieldFloat(JComboBox cb, JTextField j1) {

    String decimal = cb.getSelectedItem().toString();

    return String.format("%."+decimal+"f", Float.parseFloat(j1.getText()));

}

public void PasarTextFieldATabla(JTable j, JTextField t1, JTextField t2, JComboBox cb1, JComboBox cb2) {

    int fila = 10;

    if (t1.getText().length() > 0 && t2.getText().length() > 0) {

        for(int i = 0; i<fila; i++ ) {

            if(j.getValueAt(i, 0)==null) {


                j.setValueAt(Float.parseFloat(FormatearTextFieldFloat(cb1,t1)), i, 0);
                j.setValueAt(Float.parseFloat(FormatearTextFieldFloat(cb2,t2)), i, 1);

                break;

            }



        }

    }  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacer un

```
double numeroX = Double.parseDouble(cajaX.getText());
int decimales = Integer.parseInt(combo.getSelectedItem().toString());
double numeroRedondeado = redondearDecimales(numeroX,decimales);


public static double redondearDecimales(double valorInicial, int numeroDecimales) {
    double parteEntera, resultado;
    resultado = valorInicial;
    parteEntera = Math.floor(resultado);
    resultado=(resultado-parteEntera)*Math.pow(10, numeroDecimales);
    resultado=Math.round(resultado);
    resultado=(resultado/Math.pow(10, numeroDecimales))+parteEntera;
    return resultado;
}
```

eso te redondearia el decimal que introdujeses en la caja segun los decimales que le marcases en el ComboBox , no se si te ayuda en algo, no lo puse en comentarios debido a mi baja reputacion.Despues al darle al boton ingresar tan solo tendrias que recoger la variable numeroFinal para introducir la coordenada x en la tabla.

Comment: Gracias por tu Rta Marcos, pero lo probé, y al momento de hacer el round, me dice que dicha funcion solo recibe 1 solo parámetro.